# Why does crontab works with wildcards (*) but not with numbers?

Tags: shell-script, cron, raspbian

I want to run a script every day at 10:25 (exact hour is not important) on my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Jessie).

With that line : `25 10 * * * /home/pi/test.sh`
it gave no results, no output and no activity log.

I tried with `* * * * * /home/pi/test.sh` and there magic happens ! It worked fine, producing `CMD (/home/pi/test.sh)` in the cron logs, and creating the desired output file.

The script I used for test purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date` > /home/pi/test.txt
```

Does someone has any idea on why cron doesn't run the script ?

Comment: You have a probable copy/paste typo of a backtick at the end of the script. Also simpler: `date > ...test.txt`

Comment: Did you check the time zone on your Raspberry Pi? Does running just `date` on the command line return the time you expect?

Comment: @dhag date gave me the time I expected, but it seems (see comments to answer below) that cron is using UTC time, no matter which timezone is set on the RPi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the crontab manpage

> Commands are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month of
>   year fields match the current time, and at least one of the two day
>   fields (day of month, or day of week) match the current time

You are required to have one of the day fields. If you want this to run at 10:25 every day, just use

```
25 10 * * 0-6 /home/pi/test.sh
```

**EDIT:** This is actually incorrect because all * mark the crontab as executing every minute. We figured out it was system time issue. Double-check your system time. The cron daemon operates off of UTC. Since the script worked when you set all the fields to *, we know the actual logic is working.

Comment: If so, how come `@hourly` is listed as an alias for `0 0 * * *`?

Comment: I tried your solution, but without success.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've seen other examples where just having the time works too, not sure why in this case OP's solution isn't working.  I'm still looking into it.

Comment: @JerryMagnin What are you using to edit the crontab? `crontab -e`? And by that, I mean are you editing your pi user's crontab or the system crontab at /etc/crontab

Comment: @Patrick yes, and changes are OK (no warning message, logs saying that crontab edit is done). I’m editing my user crontab.

Comment: What are you using to test the `25 10 * * * /home/pi/test.sh` run? `run-parts` or something else?

Comment: I don't use run-parts, I just change the minutes (and hour if needed) to match current time + 3 minutes, and I monitor `/var/log/cron.log`.

Comment: I'm guessing it might be time-related. The system will execute it based on the cron daemon's idea of the current time. Since you successfully tested with all `*`, we know it works, but I think the cron daemon isn't executing it at the time you think it's supposed to execute. Try setting the crontab entry to the UTC time for execution.

Comment: Huh? "at least one of the two day fields [...] match the current time" means that a star in those fields will always match, unless the asker is using a seriously weird version of cron.

Comment: @Patrick It worked ! I was trapped by cron logs: they use system time, so I thought that cron used the same. Thanks. Could you edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted ?

Comment: Absolutely. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @dhag Yes, this was an oversight on my part. We figured it out being a system time issue.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify I would have the job listed as:

```
25 10 * * * date > /home/pi/test.txt
```

This will run at 10:25am. If it doesn't run at this time check the timezone in `/etc/default/cron` and change it if needed. After the change you will want to restart the service `service cron restart`.